# Where to convert input type for database if its type is different on the webpage

Tags: sql-server, angular, spring-boot

I'm making a new project where the frontend is angular 7, my backend is springboot and i have mssql as database. My question is that I have different input type on frontend than on database so it can't store the data.

I have this code for my inputs on the frontend which appears as a select field with the days of week

`regDay: FormGroup`

```
  { days: 'Monday' },
  { days: 'Tuesday' },
  { days: 'Wednesday' },
  { days: 'Thursday' },
  { days: 'Friday' },
  { days: 'Saturday' },
  { days: 'Sunday' }
];
```

and my database can store in a format of numbers from 0-7 (0 = sunday, 1 = monday and so on), the input type is fix in database so i can't change it there, I'm new to coding and i don't know where can i convert the input types to be good for the database.

So basically i need an outcome for e.g. i select monday on the webpage and my database gets it as a number in this case as number 1.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **enums**

```
enum DayEnum { 
  SUNDAY = 0,
  MONDAY = 1,
  ... etc
}
```

For more details follow this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Comment: thanks i will try it and if it works fine i will accept your answer